# Update column based on itself (having only a initial value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I send you this question. I'm still learning about SQL and the Dedicated SQL Pool environment (Azure Synapse Analytics), where I need to implement this.

I have a table to which I must update a column based on the values ​​of itself (having as a reference an initial value and having conditions to group)

For example:

```
# | ProductID | date       | column_a   | column_b
___________________________________________________
1 | AAAA      | 2020-05-08 | 500        | 500
___________________________________________________
2 | AAAA      | 2020-05-09 | 502        | NULL
___________________________________________________
3 | AAAA      | 2020-05-10 | 507        | NULL
___________________________________________________
4 | BBBB      | 2020-06-01 | 100        | 100
___________________________________________________
5 | BBBB      | 2020-06-02 | 105        | NULL
___________________________________________________
6 | BBBB      | 2020-06-03 | 107        | NULL
___________________________________________________
7 | BBBB      | 2020-06-04 | 108        | 110
___________________________________________________
8 | BBBB      | 2020-06-05 | 109        | NULL
___________________________________________________
```

To get the *column_b* value, I need to calculate geometric mean of the previous day's *column_b* value and the current day's *column_a* value, which is:

`` `column_b (t) = ( column_a (t) * column_b (t-1) ) ^ (0.5)` ``

Where 't' is the day to update. It is needed to consider the *ProductID* column in order to group them and update.
Also, In the case *column_b* has a non-null value, this value would be a new reference for subsequent dates (as you can see in for the 'BBBB' product)

So the desired result should be:

```
# | ProductID | date       | column_a   | column_b
___________________________________________________
1 | AAAA      | 2020-05-08 | 500        | 500
___________________________________________________
2 | AAAA      | 2020-05-09 | 502        | 500.9990
___________________________________________________
3 | AAAA      | 2020-05-10 | 507        | 503.9906
___________________________________________________
4 | BBBB      | 2020-06-01 | 100        | 100
___________________________________________________
5 | BBBB      | 2020-06-02 | 105        | 102.4695
___________________________________________________
6 | BBBB      | 2020-06-03 | 107        | 104.7103
___________________________________________________
7 | BBBB      | 2020-06-04 | 108        | 110
___________________________________________________
8 | BBBB      | 2020-06-05 | 109        | 109.4988
___________________________________________________
```

As you can see, to update a record in *column_b* I require data from the previous day.
It would not be a problem for the second record for each Product, but from the third and onwards I have problems.
I have been thinking about using 'update' and 'while', but I think this would be a problem on a large table.

Is there a function to be able to do this type of procedure? Or some way to use update in this case? Or maybe some other way that doesn't consume a lot of resources when traversing the table.

Don't forget this is for Dedicated SQL Pool (Azure Synapse). Some variables and statements from T-SQL/SQL-Server are not supported here, what is a bit troublesome.

Thank you in advance. I have stuck in this implementation with the knowledge I have at this time.
Sorry my bad english.

Comment: You're probably going to need a recursive query. Performance is going to be great. Is the first `column_b` always the same as the first `column_a` per `ProductID`?

Comment: Regarding the first value of `column b`... They are not necessarily the same as `column a`. I put it like this to make the most illustrative example possible.
 
But, also, I think we could consider a special case: For some `ProductID`, there are days where `column_b` is not null (not only the first value).


Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what would you do for such days?

Comment: In the case `column_b` has a not null value, this value would be a new reference for subsequent dates.
I did a little edit in the question to consider that situation. Hope it's understandable.
If not, we can ignore that case.

Answer (score 0):

To me I think its a bigger challenge was to curate / munch the data so that we can comsume that in an update statement  and I think I was able to do that below . You will have use a loop and update the table . Since every rows value is dependent on the last row , so there is no other ( as per me ) but to use the loop .

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT  
( 
id int , 
ProductID  varchar(100) 
,date date
,Column_a float
,Column_b float

) 
INSERT INTO product values (1,'AAAA','2020-05-08',500,500)
INSERT INTO product values (2,'AAAA','2020-05-09',502,NULL)
INSERT INTO product values (3,'AAAA','2020-05-10',507,NULL)
INSERT INTO product values (4,'BBBB','2020-06-01',100,100)
INSERT INTO product values (5,'BBBB','2020-06-02',105,NULL)
INSERT INTO product values (6,'BBBB','2020-06-03',107,NULL)



select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProductID ASC) AS Row# , ProductID,Date,Column_a
--,isnull(Column_b,Column_a) as 'Column_b'
from  (
        select A.ProductID,a.date as 'Date',a.Column_a ,b.Column_a as 'Column_b'
        from product A
         inner join product B 
           on A.date =DATEADD(day,1,b.date) 
           and A.productid = B.ProductID
           UNION 
        select A.ProductID,a.date as 'Date',a.Column_a ,b.Column_a as 'Column_b'
        from product A
         left outer join product B 
           on A.date =DATEADD(day,1,b.date) 
           and A.productid = B.ProductID 
           and a.Column_a is not null 
           )AA
           Order by date
```

[image]